# question about php decode JSON

Tags: php, json

I still have some question about php decode JSON.
the JSON return like this.

```
all({"Total":30,"Debug":null,"Documents":[
{
  "DocTitle":"Image: A municipal police officer takes positio",
  "Docmultimedia":[
        {
          "DocExpire":"2/7/2011 1:39:02 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
 ...]
});
```

this is my php code:

```
foreach ($data->Documents as $result) { 
    echo htmlspecialchars($result->DocTitle).'<br />';
    if(!empty($result->Docmultimedia)){
        echo htmlspecialchars($result->Docmultimedia->DocExpire).'<br />';
    }
}
```

It return `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.
and `echo htmlspecialchars($result->Docmultimedia->DocExpire)`, is it write right? Thanks all.

Comment: It seems you are not processing the string correctly. Otherwise `$data->Documents` would return an array.

Comment: Looks like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to me.

Comment: Did you check `$data` is not `false` and `$data->Documents` is not empty?

Comment: because of the `all(...)` at the head of the JSON data? sorry for I am a newbie.

Comment: what is that `all(...)` thing? invlid json?

Comment: @StasM, @Felix Kling, `echo $data->Documents` is empty? am i write wrong for this? I can see the JSON data like `all({"Total":30,"Debug":null,"Documents":[
{
  "DocTitle":"Image: A municipal police officer takes positio",
  "Docmultimedia":[
        {
          "DocExpire":"2/7/2011 1:39:02 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
 ...]
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Precondition*:
The question is based on an MSNBC api (http://api.msnbc.msn.com/documents/GetDocuments?keyword=usa&jsonp=all)

*Answer*:
**API Call**
You should call the API without the trailing `&jsonp=all`, this will make the json evaluateable

**API Result**
MSN returns some values with `NaN`, NaN is no valid JSON as [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) proved.

**Result Digesting**
I provide a **[working example](https://gist.github.com/771212)** on GIST for digesting.

Docmultimedia is an array, as indicated by "Docmultimedia": **[** { ... } **]**
you have to call `$result->Docmultimedia[0]->DocExpire` to retrieve it. alternatively iterate over it.

I noticed that in the APIs result no `Docmultimedia` occurs ever, instead `DocExpire` is an property of the document. Retrieve it via `$result->DocExpire`.

Comment: @cj333 could you post a (reduced) code sample on either gist or codepad (where felix and mine examples are). i could look into the code then.

Comment: @Felix Kling, @Samuel Herzog, this is the link 'http://api.msnbc.msn.com/documents/GetDocuments?keyword=usa&jsonp=all' for the url I get the jsonp.

Comment: @cj333 first of all, the parameter jsonp in the url isn't needed, this makes the quirks with `all()`. secondly, the json msn provides isnt syntactically correct. i feed JSONLint with it and it mocks for an error http://www.jsonlint.com/ (simply paste the url in). i believe thats the reason why `json_decode()` fails

Comment: @cj333: I get this error: `"Latitude":NaN`. `NaN` is not valid in JSON. Maybe you should write a bug report.

Comment: @cj333 i found an work around, give me a minute to post the code example

Comment: @cj333 Gist is now up to date and provides all those information needed. I wrapped all NaN occurences with "", so add an check for real info instead of NaN in your working application. hope that helps you :)

Comment: @cj333 I noticed there is never a child called `Docmultimedia` and that `DocExpire` is on the same level as `DocTitle` and updated my GIST according to it. You should dig into the API documents once more to get the right details ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling, @Samuel Herzog, Thanks too many for your friendly. Can I replace `NaN` into `empty`? so that the code can work?

Comment: @Samuel Herzog, yes ,'there is never a child called Docmultimedia', Ok, I will check it. excuse me, I'm test this API and changed my code for many times, looking for where is the problem. I am not sure where they gone...

Comment: @cj333 glad to help you :), i think it would be the smartest thing to replace it with `null`. if you're using my example you just have to change `$NaNReplacement` for that. Please also look for a way to fill an error report to MSNBC so they can fix the bug.

Comment: @cj333: You could do `str_replace(':NaN', ':null', $json)` or `str_replace(':NaN', ':""', $json)`. But there is always the possibility that the string contains `:NaN` at a legal position and changing it might change the data or even create another invalid string. You have to try. I would still file a bug report.

Comment: @Felix Kling, @Samuel Herzog,  I can get the data now. Thanks again, have a nice weekend :}

Comment: +1 for noticing that removing "&jsonp" already helps. @cj333: Thanks, you too :)

Comment: @Felix Kling, ok, I have removed it.

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks for the +1 @cj333 have a nice weekend too :)

Answer (score 2):

First, what you are receiving is JSONP, not pure JSON. In order to *decode* the JSON, you have to remove, `all(...);` first:

```
$data = trim($json, 'all();');
```

Second, you need to decode JSON. PHP does not do this automatically:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```

Now you should be abel to do:

```
foreach($data->Documents as $result) {
    // something
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/fgl9lyXl)

Comment: @Felix Kling if he hadn't parsed $data he whould have got an error message with the first foreach and not with the htmlspecials fnc

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: But he gets the error message: *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*. You are right though, he is accessing the other values wrongly in the loop.

Comment: @Felix Kling because the Docmultimedia Attribute is an array, that has nothing to do with decoding at all, also he already loops $data->Documents, i don't see how your answer would help

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: He writes that he is getting the error: *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().* How can you assume the loop works then?

Comment: shame on me, i guess i should check my eyes :/ nevertheless, this wouldn't make his code working completly, as proved in my answers example

Comment: @Felix Kling, @Samuel Herzog,thanks for all, I have remove the 'all(...);' it sees link a JSON now, but the `echo $data->Documents` is empty, so still warning.

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: Same for your answer ;) But the combined answer should work ;) @cj333: Then your JSON might not be 100% correct. Check the demo, it should work...

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, combination & cooperation :) @cj333 you have to encapsulate your json with '' before feeding it to `json_decode()`

Comment: @cj333: You might want to pass your JSON (without `all(..);`) to http://www.jsonlint.com/ and see if it validates.

Comment: @cj333: Not sure what you mean. JSONP is just JSON wrapped in a function call. The function call is `all(...);`. You have to remove this in order to get the JSON string. Have a look at Wikipedia for JSONP.